# C++ Adding Elements to a List in Alphabetic Order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array of Students, and I am trying to add another student to the list. I am writing the add method which will add a student to the list in alphabetic order based on their name. All the other elements in the list then will shift accordingly. This is my attempt to write it:

```
void Array::add(Student* student)
{
  if (size == MAX_STUDENTS)
    return;
  if(size == 0){
    students[0] = student;
    size ++;
  }
  if (size != 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; ++i){
      if(students[i]->getName() >= student->getName()){
        students[i-1] = student;
        size ++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

students is an array of pointers to the Student object`Student** students;`it is initialized in the constructor along with `size`

This however, does not sort the elements. I am guessing my logic is incorrect. I also do not know how to shift the elements down the array. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does `getName()` return? Best to include a [mcve].

Comment: _"students is an array of pointers to the Student objectStudent** students;"_ No, that is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Why not use an `std::priority_queue`?

Comment: @sfjac `getName()` return the student's name

Answer (score 1):

When shifting items down, start with the last item in the list and work your way up to the insertion point. Should be something along the lines of:

```
int i;
for (i = size - 1; students[i]->getName() >= student->getName(); i--)
{
    students[i+1] = students[i];
}
students[i] = student;
size++;
```

Better approaches are to have Student implement the < operator and use a [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Very inefficient, that is `O(n)`, although the best you can do if you are stuck with arrays

Comment: Agreed. I answered based on the assumption that this was an assignment and have since edited. Back in in a second to linkify a few things.